# How do i create an entry if it not exists and if it exists i just add the date?

Tags: sql, sqlite, database-design, foreign-keys, database-normalization

I have a table TRACKS with:

```
id integer NOT NULL,
title text,
artist_name text,
album_name text,
date text,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (artist_name) REFERENCES artists(name),
FOREIGN KEY (album_name) REFERENCES albums(name)
```

What i want to do is, if the entry for the song exists (same artist, same album name, same song title) to add the entry date (which is YYYY-MM-DD). I don´t care about the time, just the date.

So i have one entry for the song, but various dates when it was played. I want duplicate dates, because that way i can count number of plays.

Here are the other tables:

ALBUMS:

```
id integer NOT NULL,
title text,
artist_name text,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (artist_name) REFERENCES artists(name)
```

ARTISTS:

```
id integer NOT NULL,
name text UNIQUE,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (artist_name) REFERENCES artists(name)
```

I can use

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO artists(name) VALUES(?)
```

For artists because name is UNIQUE, but the others i don't know how to do it because different artists can have the same album name and song names.

SAMPLE DATA:

I will feed the database with "Artist", "Song", "Album" and the system date in YYYY-MM-DD format.

program.py -a "Michael Jackson" -t "Billie Jean" -d "Thriller" and the program will automatically feed the YYYY-MM-DD.

So today i give the app -a "Michael Jackson" -t "Billie Jean" -d "Thriller" three times.

Tomorrow i listen to it two more times.

I want the program to create the artist, album, song and date in the first time and add two more 2021-06-24 in TRACKS without duplicating everything else.

And tomorrow it will add 2021-06-25 two times.

It has to be in a way that i can COUNT() the number of dates to know how many times i played the song, the album or the artist.

Comment: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-replace-statement/

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: @CaiusJard wouldn't REPLACE just overwrite the date?

Comment: It's what I interpreted you meant by *if the entry for the song exists ... add the entry date*. If you meant something like "DATE is supposed to be a CSV of all the dates the song was ever played on and every insert of a dupe should extend the CSV" then for the love of good engineering, please don't do this. Put another table to track what song id was played on what date. I can't rail enough against the idea of storing the "many" end of what is natively a 1:many relationship, in a single column in the table. It's a terrible idea

Comment: @CaiusJard DATE will compound. Every time i play a song, it will just add another entry in DATE. So i should create a separate table for this? How should this work? Every new play it will record DATE and SONG_ID?

Comment: Exactly/what forpas just posted. I'd have called `LISTEN` as `playlists` but ither than that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A normalized schema for your requirement would be to have a separate table where you insert a row (with the track's id and the current timestamp) each time you listen to a track.
So, no `date` column in the table `TRACKS`.

Also, you should store the album's id in the table `TRACKS` and not its title.
This is common practice and there is a reason for it: there are albums with the same title.
Also, there is no need to store the artist, because you can get it from the album's id.

```
CREATE TABLE ALBUMS(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  title text,
  artist_id integer,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (artist_id) REFERENCES artists(id)
);

CREATE TABLE ARTISTS(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  name text UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
); 

CREATE TABLE TRACKS( 
  id integer NOT NULL,
  title text,
  album_id text,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (album_id) REFERENCES albums(id)
);

CREATE TABLE LISTEN(
  track_id integer NOT NULL,
  date TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (track_id, date),
  FOREIGN KEY (track_id) REFERENCES tracks(id)
);
```

You can insert a new row to the table `LISTEN` just by providing the track's id:

```
INSERT INTO LISTEN(track_id) VALUES (152);
```

The date will be by default the current timestamp.

Comment: *So, no date column in the table TRACKS.* - indeed, any date in the tracks table should be a date related to the track itself, such as date it was recorded, date its license runs out, whatever... And then of course it would have a better name than "date" (never name columns types) e.g. "RecordingDate" or "LicensedUntil"

Comment: @CaiusJard you are referring to a column that serves another purpose and in that case it could be something like `date_created`.

Comment: Or simply `when` ?

Comment: @forpas Yes. I totally agree with you. My comment was more aimed at the OP, really..

Comment: @crdpa `when` is an SQL keyword (case when...) . Avoid naming columns using reserved words. There isn't really a ration on characters for column names - strive to make them good and descriptive; "when"  is a bit nondescript

Comment: @crdpa this is a simplified version of the schema that you may use. In a more advance schema you would have to think about albums with more than 1 artist and tracks that may belong to more than 1 albums and even more.

Comment: @forpas yes. I'm way above my knowledge in this. Since it is a hobby learning project for personal use, i will worry about that later (if ever).

Comment: @forpas Ok. Another quick question. Let's say i input "Michael Jackson", "Billie Jean" (track), "Thriller" (album). 

I will do `INSERT INTO LISTEN(track_id) VALUES (id of Billie Jean)`.

But how should i look the track id to see which it is? I have to look if i already have that track name with the same artist.

Comment: @crdpa yes, this the right thing to do and it's done with queries: `"SELECT t.id FROM tracks t INNER JOIN albums al ON al.id = t.album_id INNER JOIN artists ar ON ar.id = al.artist_id WHERE ar.name = 'Michael Jackson' AND t.title = 'Billie Jean'"`